# How to Activate Visio/Office using live.account

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm trying to use my live account license to activate Microsoft Visio on my Windows 7 desktop. I was able to install it; but I'm getting this friendly little message from Visio when attempting to start and activate:

> The account XXXX@XXXXX isn't associated with this Office product.  To activate this install, please sign in with the account associated with your product.  If you purchased Office for yourself, use the same account that you used when purchasing Office.  If you recieve Office through organization or school, please contact your administrator. If you have a product key, go back and select "Enter a product key instead."

I used my live account to download and install Microsoft Visio, so why is it giving me this message?  Any help or hints appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried calling Microsoft support yet?  Exactly which version and edition of Visio is this?  What did you mean by "PNS" mean in "Windows 7 PNS"?

Comment: I have contacted my company IT guy; apparently this is an MSDN subscription install, sorry.  This is Visio Professional 2013.

Answer (score 1):

So I neglected to note that this was installed via MSDN, which is connected to my live account.  Upon contacting IT, I was instructed to go online and download a product key via MSDN.